# How to create a python package with modules and submodules

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I am learning how to create Python packages containing modules and submodules to publish my future work into PyPi.

To get started, I watched this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urE5MuYd-YM) and, for learning purposes, I tried to write my own version of the famous [Cowsay program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowsay) but in [python language](https://github.com/VaasuDevanS/cowsay-python) adding to it new animals in submodules.

My start of a package can be found in [github](https://github.com/gloriamacia/animal_say) and it follows this structure:

```
animal_say/
    __init__.py
    talk.py
    farm/
        __init__.py
        animals.py
    home/
        __init__.py
        animals.py
```

I manage to import the module by doing `python` and then `import animal_say` but doing `animal_say.talk(cow, "hello world")` return an error as talk function is not found.

Comment: You need to add the root folder into a PYTHONPATH env. variable. When you finish your package, you will add setup.py file, which will allow you to install the package, in which case adding it to the path is not required

Comment: Try changing `animal-say` to `animal_say`